# Populating drop down list : (using struts framework)

Tags: list, dynamic, struts, drop-down-menu

I know this is a very common question. I have spent hours and hours searching to get a right answer but am still not clear with it. Can anyone help me?

I have 3 drop down lists( "A", "B", "C") in html form. Initially  B and C are disabled. I am populating "A"
by  calling a Url with some connection parameters and finally parsing it to get a Arraylist which i set in my Action form class.

When a user selects an item from the "A" drop down, i want to enable B drop down and populate it with data by connecting to a URL with selected value of A dropdown as connection parameter.

For this:  am calling a onchange event on A dropdown like onchange = "changeA();"

I am submitting the form to my action class. I am stuck at this point.

What do i do next ????
Thanks!

Comment: Is it Ajax based request or not?

Answer (score 0):

By your question its not clear whether you are using AJAX or not. If you are using AJAX then you can make a ajax call to the second url and parse the response XML. If you are not using AJAX then you have to set some type of request parameter which preserve the value of you your previous selections.